# Scroll to correct position in SwiftUI when a list item is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've a SwiftUI `ForEach` loop which contains views that expand when clicked. Something similar to the view shown below.

```
struct ExpandingView: View {
    
    @State var isExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello!")
            if isExpanded {
                Text("World")
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                isExpanded.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In theory, I can use the `ScrollViewReader` and `scrollTo` a particular position.

```
ScrollViewReader { view in
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { id in
             ExpandingView()
                 .id(id)
                 .padding()                        
        }
    }
}
```

However, in practice, I'm not sure how to get the `id` from within the view (because `onTapGesture` is in the view) and propagate it up one level.

The other option is to have the `onTapGesture` in the `ForEach` loop, but then I'm not sure how to toggle the `isExpanded` flag for the correct view.

Comment: inside the if isExpanded condition have an only single view? or multiple views for scrolling'?

Comment: @RajaKishan Inside the `if isExpanded` there is no scrolling required. The scrolling part is one level up i.e. when the views themselves are displayed with the help of `ForEach` loop.

Comment: where you want to click action for scrolling to particular row?

Comment: @RajaKishan Since the entire row is tappable, I'm flexible putting it out on the `ForEach` loop as well. But as of now, it is within the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `ScrollViewProxy` to row view and then you can now able to scroll.

```
struct ExpandingView: View {
    
    @State var isExpanded = false
    var id: Int
    var proxy: ScrollViewProxy
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello!")
            if isExpanded {
                Text("World")
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                isExpanded.toggle()
                proxy.scrollTo(id, anchor: .center)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestScrollView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { view in
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { id in
                    ExpandingView(id: id, proxy: view)
                        .id(id)
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any consequences to this approach, like accidentally leaking memory or anything in particular to be aware of? I'm asking this because I plan to use it in conjunction with `LazyVStack` on the parent view.

Comment: No. We are not doing any heavy or unrelated tasks. We are just passing scroll proxy same as normal param. If your view has images or full-size images then it will spike memory some time else by this code you no need to worry about this.